# What to do when visa is in administrative processing and PhD program is starting?

Tags: visa

I'm a 1st year admitted Ph.D. student at an Ivy League University and a former Fulbrighter. I'd like to ask for your advice on my situation. I have applied for the F1 visa at the American Consulate and had the interview on July 17th. My application is under the "administrative processing" since then despite submitting all of the required documents on the same day of the request, July 17th. Note that I'm fully funded by the graduate school. My program starts September 1st, and I'm worried that I won't make it on time. Should I ask the school to defer my admission (which is unlikely as I've been told by a faculty), or ask my university advisor to try to reach the concerned authorities? I have worked very hard to receive such an admission offer by an extremely selective university and program and I'd appreciate any help in how to overcome this unnecessary delay.

Comment: How did your new department answer when you asked them this question? (You _did_ ask them, didn't you?)

Answer (score 2):

The [US state department](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/wait-times.html/) says that wait times for administrative processing are usually less than 60 days, and they don't allow complaints or inquiries before those 60 days have passed.

July 17th sounds really late for PhD admission. You should have applied for a visa when you were admitted, probably back in April, or May at the latest, especially if you are in a country likely to have more scrutiny of visas.

You can talk to your department and inform them of the delay and ask how they would like to to proceed, but this seems like it falls under the category of "your fault" and there isn't anything your university can or should do to expedite the process. If your visa was denied for some incorrect reason (like they didn't believe you were admitted as a student), then the university would be of more help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. I was taking a summer course in the States, thus couldn't go to my country and apply for a new visa. I've applied as soon as I was back! I've provided support letters from the university stating my enrollment and funding.

Comment: @Kushan I don't think Bryan meant that you were personally at fault (hence the scare quotes), but in the sense that it's not the university's fault or the government's fault, ergo, technically the blame goes to you, regardless whether it was in your power.  It's a unfortunate situation, and most departments will be understanding (but their hands may be tied by central university policies), so talking to them is your best bet, but I'd be packed and ready to leave at a moment's notice too.

Comment: Yes thank you @guifa, that was indeed my point. Given those circumstances I'd expect your department to give you some leeway, but communicate with them as soon as possible and explain the situation. I'm sure you aren't the first incoming student to have experienced some visa troubles, and hopefully the delay will be minimal.

Comment: I'll do so, thanks guys. I wasn't aware before of the possibility of such a delay coming from where I'm and having such an admission offer, but in the current political climate, anything is possible.